# Как с помощью одного radiobutton добавить несколько значений в таблицу?

Tags: php, mysqli

К примеру есть таблица с полями: Возраст, пол, работа. И несколько радиобаттонов на форме: Петр, Василий, Маша, Лена. При выборе к примеру радиобаттона "Лена", в таблицу добавлялись несколько значений: 27 лет, женский, менеджер. Как сделать добавление нескольких значений в таблицу при выборе только одного радиобаттноа ? И вообще можно ли так ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если задача состоит в том, чтобы отправить какие-либо данные, которых не видит пользователь. То можно либо скрыть данные в теге form, либо сделать XHR запрос, в котором сайт будет отправлять необходимые данные

**1 Способ состоит в том, чтобы отправить скрытые данные, вместе с формой**

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <!-- ЭТИ ПОЛЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ НЕ ВИДИТ, НО ОНИ ОТПРАВЛЯЮТСЯ НА PHP ОБРАБОТЧИК -->
    <input type="hidden" name="gender" value="[YOUR_VALUE_GENDER]">
    <input type="hidden" name="age" value="[YOUR_VALUE_AGE]">
    <input type="hidden" name="role" value="[YOUR_VALUE_MANADGER]">

    <!-- ЭТИ ПОЛЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ МОЖЕТ ИЗМЕНИТЬ, ОДНАКО ЗНАЧЕНИЕ В СКРЫТЫХ ПОЛЯХ НЕ ИЗМЕНИТСЯ -->
    <input type="radio" id="contactChoice1" name="contact" value="Пётр">
    <label for="contactChoice1">Пётр</label>

    <input type="radio" id="contactChoice2" name="contact" value="Василий">
    <label for="contactChoice2">Василий</label>

    <input type="radio" id="contactChoice3" name="contact" value="Маша">
    <label for="contactChoice3">Маша</label>

    <input type="radio" id="contactChoice4" name="contact" value="Лена">
    <label for="contactChoice4">Лена</label>

    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

**2 Способ - отправлять данные по событию, через XHR Запрос**
Вы можете отправить нужные данные, прямо при выборе radioButton. В примере ниже предоставлены статические данные, однако, вы можете изменить их любым. удобным для вас методом

HTML код радио кнопок теперь выглядит так

```
<!-- Отправка данных происходит по нажатию на радиоКнопку  -->
<input type="radio" id="contactChoice2" name="contact" value="Василий" onclick="hideSend(this);">
<label for="contactChoice2">Василий</label>

<input type="radio" id="contactChoice3" name="contact" value="Маша" onclick="hideSend(this);">
<label for="contactChoice3">Маша</label>

<input type="radio" id="contactChoice4" name="contact" value="Лена" onclick="hideSend(this);">
<label for="contactChoice4">Лена</label>
```

JavaSrupt код для отправки данных, при выборе радикнопки:

```
// Функция, для отправки скрытых данных 
function hideSend (valueName) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //  Формируем список отправляемых параметров 
    var params =
                 'gender=' + encodeURIComponent('[YOUR_VALUE_GENDER]') +
                 '&age=' + encodeURIComponent('[YOUR_VALUE_GENDER]') + 
                 '&role=' + encodeURIComponent('[YOUR_VALUE_MANADGER]') +
                //   Значение нажатого инпута
                 '&name=' + encodeURIComponent(valueName);

    xhr.open(
        "GET", // Тип отправки GET | POST
        '/submit?' + params, // Путь до PHP обработчика 
        true);

    xhr.send();
}
```

После получения данных от пользователя. добавьте необходимые данные, при помощи PHP Обработчика

Comment: Подскажите, а как конкретно задать значения для отдельных радиобаттонов ? То есть для Маши добавятся одни, для Петра другие. Вот это не могу понять.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю вопрос. Буквально, если пользователь выбирает "Маша", то должны отправляться примерно вот такие данные "27 лет, женский, менеджер", если "Петя" то "35 лет, мужской, разработчик" и так далее?